# Pandas: dataframe.apply() - Include seperate dataframe to the function

Tags: python, pandas

## EDIT

How do I include a separate dataframe to a `df.apply` function.

e.g.

I have a dataframe called `df` and `df_location`

Function

```py
def meas(row, df_location):
    vehicle = df_location[((df_location.TS > row.DATETIME_FROM) & (df_location.TS < row.DATETIME_TO)) & (df_location.ROAD == int(row.ROAD))].VID
    if vehicle.nunique() == 1:
        return vehicle.iloc[0]
    else:
        return False
```

```py
df["VID"] = df.apply(meas, axis=1) #Here is where I want to include df_location
```

I can solve it like this instead, but this doesn't look like the "right" way.

```
for x, y in df.iterrows():
    y = meas(y, df_location)
    df["VID"].loc[x] = y
```

I can't seem to figure out how to include a dataframe to the function called from the `apply`,
or maybe this is not the right way.?

Comment: Why do you need to do so? Can you provide some context for this?

Comment: @AMC,

I have 2 different dataframes, coming from different subsystems.

1 of the dataframes have some sensor data, while the other dataframe includes the data for which vehicle was triggering the sensor to activate,
now I need to link the Vehicle ID to the triggered sensor data.
(Basically sensor was triggered at this time, which vehicle was inside the triggerzone within this timeframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the args parameter of apply to pass extra positional arguments to your function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
df.apply(meas, axis=1, args=(df_location))
```

Comment: Hej @Fish11,

I did try that, but it didn't seem to work for me, it returns the error:
```ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```